# Insert text before link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
$( "test" ).insertAfter( ".mdr" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="mdr">HEllow</span>
```

I want to insert text (no within a `div` or `p`) **after the **`span`****.

I try this but it does not work.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( ".mdr" ).after( "Test" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="mdr">HEllow</span>
```

Comment: I want 'test' outside the span not inside

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use `after()` in this case.

For example: `$(".mdr").after("Hello")`

---

Read more about the `after()` method here: http://api.jquery.com/after/.

See it in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xau36ydu/).

Answer (score 0):

You need [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$(".mdr").after("<div>Hey</div>");
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/98oqrs06/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways you could do this, but here are 2 examples:

**1.** Use the CSS selector :after and add the class with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<span class="mdr">Hello</span>
```

JS:

`$( ".mdr" ).addClass('textAfter');`

CSS:

```
`.textAfter:after {
  content: 'Text';
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}`
```

I set up a [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGJwOg) that shows how to use this with jQuery...

**2.** Use the jQuery html property: `$( ".mdr" ).html( "<span>Hello</span>, my text here." );`